# Alignment Question

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to make one column of exercises on the left and then the solutions on the right. It makes the coding easier (I think) if the solutions are on the same line as the exercise.

Other than tables, is there an easy way to make this happen? I.e. to tell ALL solutions to be left-aligned at a horizontally absolute position?

Thanks!

This is roughly what I would like

[image]

This is what my code is. It does not line up the solutions properly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{int(random(0,20)-10)}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{int(random(0,20)-10)}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{int(\a+\b)}
}

\newcommand{\blank}{\_\_\_\_\_}

\newcommand{\RandomSum}
{
\large
\InitVariables
\huge\(\a+\b=\)\blank \hspace{2cm} \(\a+\b=\c\)
% What do I write instead of \hspace{2cm} here?

\vspace{0.8cm}
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\end{document}
```

P.S. I don't care which font it is, regardless of what I used in the picture.

Comment: Keywords: `tabular`, `array`, `aligned`, `alignedat` and more.

Comment: I believe that `tabular` and `array` make my code much more complex as I use a macro to generate both the exercises and solutions. What are `aligned` and `alignedat`?

Comment: So, you use macros to generate the code. Are you willing to share them with us by creating a minimal working example? That way we can present a solution specifically for your needs.

Comment: I could certainly do that. I think that I will be able to fix my macros on my own , though, if I knew how to make what was in the picture in the OP. Should I make a MWE any way?

Comment: Just posted a MWE. Didn't take as long as I thought it would.

Comment: I posted a possible way. Autocalculating makes this one harder. It is very essential to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{int(random(0,20)-10)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{int(random(0,20)-10)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{int(\a+\b)}%
}

\newcommand{\RandomSum}{%
  \InitVariables\edef\x{$\a\checkplus\b=$ & $\a\checkplus\b=\c$\noexpand\\}\x
}
\newcommand{\checkplus}[1]{\ifnum#1<0 \else+\fi#1}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{2cm}}l}
Exercises & Solutions \\
\hline
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, too! I think I may have asked before, but what does `\edef` do differently from other similar commands? Also, why did you have to write `\noexpand`?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything `\edef` causes the expansion of the variables and of `\checkplus`; but we don't want ``\\`` to expand.

Comment: Got it. How does the `\checkplus` command work?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything It checks whether the next token expands to a negative integer and, in this case, it outputs nothing; otherwise, it outputs `+`.

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion using boxes of no width and phantom spaces.

[image: wecanlearnanythingMathHorizontalAlig]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{int(random(0,20)-10)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{int(random(0,20)-10)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{int(\a+\b)}
}

\newcommand{\blank}{\rule{2em}{.4pt}}

\newcommand{\RandomSum}
{\LARGE%
    \InitVariables%
    $\mathrlap{\a + \b=\blank }$%
\phantom{This is the needed spacing}
$\a+\b=\c$\bigbreak
       % What do I write instead of \hspace{2cm} here?
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\RandomSum
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks great! I don't quite understand it, though. Can you point me in the right direction to read about `\mathrlap`, `\phantom`, and `\bigbreak`? I am not familiar with those commands.

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything `mathrlap` is from package `mathtools`, but the mechanism is probably explained, along with `\phantom` and `bigbreak` in some more advanced book about LaTeX. Knowing something about TeX will be good as well.

Comment: Hmm... I definitely don't know anything about TeX, so perhaps this is code I just won't be able to grock... Perhaps I should just memorize it?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything You can dissect the solution and try out the different parts indvidually to see what they do. And then memorize what they do. That is what i have done.